# Elastic Search and Spark

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to set up spark and Eleastic search using the `elasticsearch-spark` library with the sbt artifact: `"org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark" % "2.3.2"`. When I try to configure eleastic search with this code:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[2]")
.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")     
.set("es.resource", "test")
.set("es.nodes", "test.com:9200")
```

I keep getting the error: `illegal character` for all of the set statements above for elastic search. Anyone know the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have copied the code from any website or any other blog. It contains unreadable characters that are actually giving you trouble.

Simple solution: Delete all the content. Type one by one manually, and run it.. Let me know if you faced any problems again, i will help you out.

Comment: Yup that was the problem. I copied it from a website and it put in some illegal characters and my IntelliJ IDE wasn't able to read it. I just deleted all of the text and retyped it and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Do you think you can help me with a problem I have with saving data from spark to elastic search?

Comment: Certainly... Please let me know your problem.. I will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set the http.publish_host in your elasticsearch.yml to HOST_NAME. The es-hadoop connector is sniffing the nodes from the _nodes/transport API so it checks what the published http address is.